# Using getmap for xelatex: how to --enable-write18 on MikTex

Tags: getmap

I want to use the LaTeX package `getmap` to create maps in my pdf-documents. I use Windows 10, MikTex 2.9, and the editor TexWorks in XeLaTeX mode. The `getmap` manual (p.12) tells me I have to enable `\write18` by using the command `--enable-write18` in MikTex.

Unfortunately, I have not clue as to how to add this command to my system.

How do I add the command?

Can it be added permanently?

Will getmap work with XeLaTeX?

Comment: do not add it permanently. It is disabled by default with good reason. If you run with shell escape enabled and you run any tex document that you find on the internet (eg this site) then it could do _anything_ that you could do on the machine. delete all your files, mail your files to some other site....

Comment: in the texworks properties, tab "typesetting" (or something like that) create a new profile e.g. xelatex-shell-escape, copy the settings from the existing xelatex profile and add `--shell-escape` to the arguments.

Comment: Once -shell-escape is active the getmapdl (map downloader) application should be available to use from any file format. To test if it is an active package in MiKTeX run MiKTeX-console and look for the package installed date also there will be an example tex file in the MiKTeX texmfs\install\doc\latex\getmap folder to copy then play with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `getmap` example will work with XeLaTeX (as stated by the **author Josef in comments below** it should work with all engines not just pdfLaTeX) so here is the package example that was processed by XeLaTeX and a string of instructions to **add shell escape to existing** typesetting choices (note David Carlisle's warning to **NOT USE** these elevated compilation commands **on files or links you do not trust**)

I show how to modify both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX in image below but you only need to modify XeLaTeX as desired.

**Sorry** after posting I found the TeXworks editor **modifies your existing** commands NOT added a new one **so you need to do as Ulrike mentioned** add a new "Tool Configuration" and copy the XeLaTeX settings WITHOUT shell escape (slowly/carefully) so you have a choice of both.

[image]

Comment: As author of `getmap`, I just want to add that there is no implicit recommendation to use `pdflatex`! Read the hint in the example as 'You must use the `--shell-escape` switch'. The download of maps will work will all engines. Otherwise nice answer! ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks! I will test out your solution.

Comment: if a add \usepackage{getmap} the compilation process stops at this point:
("C:\Users\esdo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\rerunfilec
heck.sty")). What can be wrong? I am using windows10, and TexWorks

Comment: Generally had no issues so need to doublecheck  how you configured and what file commands you are running I see no evidence of running that sty file so which tex file are you running if it is one of your own we would need a small version in the question with a preamble to see what triggers that sty file